# java arraylist<String> seems to overwrite existing items when using the add() method

Tags: java, arraylist, foreach

I am trying to read lines from a configuration file and append each line into an `ArrayList` using the `add()` method.

However when I go to print the contents of the `ArrayList` through the use of a `foreach`, it only prints the last item to be entered. It seems to me like the add() method may not be appending properly? I also tried using a **generic for loop** instead of `foreach` and still the same result.

```
public static void interpret(String line){
    ArrayList<String> rooms = new ArrayList<>(); 
    ArrayList<String> rules = new ArrayList<>(); 

    // Ignore Room and Rule templates
    if(line.contains("(") && line.contains(")")){
        System.out.println("skip"); 
        return;
    }
    if(line.contains("Room;")){
        rooms.add(line);
        rooms.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
    if(line.contains("Rule;")){
        rules.add(line);
        rules.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

The output of this is below.

```
Rule; (Room: SmartObject, state{condition}, state{condition}, ...)
skip
Rule; Garden: Sprinklers, on{time=15}, off{time=16}, off{weather="raining"}
Rule; Garden: Sprinklers, on{time=15}, off{time=16}, off{weather="raining"}
Rule; Kitchen: Coffee machine, on{time=6}, off{time=12}
Rule; Kitchen: Coffee machine, on{time=6}, off{time=12}
```

It is mixed in with the actual text lines from the file its reading but as you can see it only prints the line above it, which was the last line to be appended into the `ArrayList`.

It should look something like this.

```
Rule; (Room: SmartObject, state{condition}, state{condition}, ...)
skip
Rule; Garden: Sprinklers, on{time=15}, off{time=16}, off{weather="raining"}
Rule; Garden: Sprinklers, on{time=15}, off{time=16}, off{weather="raining"}
Rule; Kitchen: Coffee machine, on{time=6}, off{time=12}
Rule; Garden: Sprinklers, on{time=15}, off{time=16}, off{weather="raining"}
Rule; Kitchen: Coffee machine, on{time=6}, off{time=12}
```

Any help/insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the problem:

`ArrayList<String> rules = new ArrayList<>();`

you are creating a new ArrayList each time, instead of adding to an existing one

**Suggestion:**

1. Pass in the existing arraylist to your method OR
2. Declare a member variable at the class level

Comment: Oh of course, my apologies i should have seen that sooner. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following method singature:

```
public static void interpret(List<String> rooms, List<String> rules, String line){

    // Ignore Room and Rule templates
    if(line.contains("(") && line.contains(")")){
        System.out.println("skip"); 
        return;
    }
    if(line.contains("Room;")){
        rooms.add(line);
        rooms.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
    if(line.contains("Rule;")){
        rules.add(line);
        rules.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

}
```

Instead of creating the lists every time this function is called, create the lists in the caller function and pass to this method.